# Switch to mysqli or stay with mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

We have an app here that has been in development (and now in production) for more than a year. Which has in total over 500 `mysql_*` calls.

Is it worth it to switch **all** of the `mysql_*` in the code to `mysqli_*`

Is it worth chasing all the bugs that might (and most probably will) come about?

I see from questions like this: [Changing this from MySQL to MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4640520/561731) that just adding `i` after every `mysql*` call can lead me to alot of errors.  Is it worth my time?

`mysql_*` will probably around for the long haul (even amongst rumors of deprecation), so it it really worth any programmers time to methodically switch over?

[See also this discussion](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-214046.html)

Comment: PHP team is about to deprecate the `mysql_*` functions in future PHP releases. Read: http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799

Comment: @Buddy, if by "about to" you mean "maybe, possibly, in several years, thinking about starting to consider to".  Education through  documentation is all that will happen in the short/medium term.

Comment: @salathe, if by "short/medium term" you mean 1-2 years, you shouldn't use `musql_*` in new projects. Deprecation is all that will happen with this extension in PHP.

Comment: @Buddy, yes. Documentation changes only at first, maybe in the future deprecation then eventually PECLisation. For new code, or where convenient, use the more modern extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the [manual for `ext/mysqli`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php):

> The mysqli extension has a number of benefits, the key enhancements over the mysql extension being:
>
> - Object-oriented interface
> - Support for Prepared Statements
> - Support for Multiple Statements
> - Support for Transactions
> - Enhanced debugging capabilities
> - Embedded server support
>
> Note: If you are using MySQL versions 4.1.3 or later it is strongly recommended that you use this extension.

If you need just one of those features and can afford the refactoring, then yes, go for it. If you dont need any of those features then dont do it. There is no reason to refactor if there is no benefits.

[On a sidenote, the rumors are true. ext/mysql **will likely** be deprecated](http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=131031747409271&w=2) (although no one can say when at the time of this writing. It certainly wont be deprecated with 5.4. and it will likely be available as a pecl extension forever) In any case, you shouldnt be starting any new projects with ext/mysql anymore when you have a superior extension to start with.

Also see http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2012/php-mysql-why-to-upgrade-extmysql/

Comment: I can already do transactions (be it slowly): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples and the code seems to be working fine

Comment: OOP support is lame, prepared statements are slow, multiple statements are injection-prone and embedded server is ridiculous. Honestly, there are no real benefits.

Comment: @Gordon, **will** should be replaced with **is very likely to**. You can't say what **will** happen in PHP-land any more than we can.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the benefit of MySQLi is when it is used in an object-oriented fashion, and with prepared statements.  You get some additional versatility from it using the procedural style too, such as nice wrapper functions around transaction handling, but I think not enough to justify unless you rewrite lots of your code to make use of them.

And if you were to undertake the effort to convert to OO code or prepared statements, you might as well convert to the more flexible PDO instead of to MySQLi.

**Update Jan 2013**

Just found this old answer, and in the Aug 2011 comment thread below I said it wasn't worth it to convert `mysql_query()` calls to `mysqli_query()` absent an accompanying move to prepared statements.  It now *IS* necessary to start moving in that direction, as the `mysql_*()` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and will eventually be removed.

Comment: yes but is it worth my time to switch over an app with has over 500  `mysql_*` calls?

Comment: @Neal I would say it isn't, unless you need to use MySQLi's improved wrappers around transaction commit/rollback, etc.

Comment: PDO is a good choice, but in a shared server you can't use suhosin.sql.user_prefix http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.sql.user_prefix

Comment: @Michael -- I am still able to do transactions with `mysql_*` at least it seems to work for me

Comment: @Michael -- see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples

Comment: @Neal Transactions are tidier with MySQLi but if you are already doing them with `mysql_query("COMMIT")` there's not a good reason to switch to `mysqli_commit()`.

Comment: Except parameterized statements.

Answer (score 1):

MySQLi has some performance benefits over MySQL. Actually it's recommended to use MySQLi instead of MySQL. You can do the procedural style as well.

You could create a new branch of your app and change the code to `mysqli_*` functions. This should be pretty straight forward and while doing so you would review your database access code which might help in going on after the switch to mysqli to continue refactoring. If it's all too much hassle, you already benefit from the improved version of the client library in your database access code.

Comment: "MySQLi has some performance benefits over MySQL"? That's news, where did you get that info from? It always seems to be the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Deprecation of ext/mysql is not a rumor.

However, it is not your real problem.

Your main problem is that you're using naked API calls all over the code instead of using some intelligent library to handle SQL queries.

So, you'd better start to develop such a library or get a ready made one, and then rewrite your code to use it's calls.

Don't you see that all this repeated stuff

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT STUFF");
while($row = mysql_fetch){
    $var=$row['col'];
}
```

being incredibly boring?
why not to use some one-liner like

```
$data = $db->getRow("SELECT stuff");
```

which is shorter and can have a lot of features like query logging, counting, debugging, error handling and such?

And, as a side effect of using such a library, the only place where you will need to change whatever API calls will be only this library code.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, You should not use mysql_* function directly in your logic. You should write a wrapper.  So when you want to switch `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`, you only have to change the code of the wrapper.

Comment: Preventing bugs depends on your test.

Comment: @Neal What I means is the same as Col. Shrapnel's answer, your  problem is that you're using naked API calls all over the code...

Comment: so your saying to make a mysql class?

Comment: @Neal Make a db access class with driver class, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you have that many calls then I suggest you start by implementing (selecting or building) an abstraction layer for your database calls and then convert that.

The biggest benefit (a substantial one) in my similar exercise was the fact that mysqli offers parameterized statements allowing you to leave mysql_real_escape_string etc. behind.  But the map from one to the other isn't nearly one-to-one.

Comment: you are the second one to say to use an `abstraction layer`, how do I do that?

Comment: PDO is an abstraction layer. It offers a class with methods and properties that are closer to what happens in a procedural language, and typically richer and more consistent conceptually. Or for example the one I wrote is a class from which I do everything I need with $db->SqlExecute($sql), SqlRows($sql), SqlOneRow($sql), SqlExists($sql), and SqlOneValue($sql). Just encapsulates patterns you are confortable with. My personal preference is to have a very thin filter between SQL and PHP.

Comment: @Neal PDO is very lame abstraction layer. It's better to find something more reliable

Comment: Not recommending or judging, just giving examples. Obviously I don't use it - I think the conceptual abstractions are awkward. I don't want a third thinking level - I want to interface SQL and PHP (which are already necessary) as closely as possible without conceptual overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Advice:
If you're going to do a switch, do not switch to mysqli, instead  switch to using PDO.  If you must switch to mysqli, make sure you use it in the PHP5 OO way.  Don't use mysqli OO and old mysql at the same time or the old mysql and PDO at the same time unless  you like unexpected connection squashing.