# PHP select from not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do to a user-pass validation. Updated code:

```
$username="------";
$password="------";
$database="------";
$host = "------";


mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

echo 'username: ' . $username . '<br>';  //myname
echo 'password: ' . $password . '<br>';  //mypass

function checkpass()
{
    //$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM REG_USERS where USERNAME='$_POST[username]' and PASSWORD='$_POST[password]' ") or die(mysql_error());  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM REG_USERS where USERNAME='" . $username . "' and PASSWORD='" . $password . "'") or die(mysql_error());  
    return  mysql_num_rows($result);
}

checkpass();
echo 'checkpass:'. checkpass();
```

In the first query checkpass returns 1. In the second one it returns 0. Why?

Comment: "Doesn't work" - you should be getting an error message. Which is it? Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection....

Comment: Just as a note, make sure you escape your user inputs ALWAYS.

Comment: Like njk and Eoin say, this code is very dangerous, since it does no security. Please consider using PDO or MySQLi. Edit: Looks like it took me too long to type this :P

Comment: I use trim, stripslashes and htmlspecialchars, just removed them for simplicity.

Comment: but not the all-important addslashes?

Comment: @erdomester add more code

Comment: `trim, stripslashes and htmlspecialchars` dont escape... you need to be using `mysql_real_escape_string`. Of course you shouldnt be using `mysql_*` anyhow. You should be using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: By not working I mean that result gives me 0 rows. In the first example it finds the user-password pair.

Comment: I don't believe that line of code is wrong.

Comment: Have you ever considered enabling `error_reporting(E_ALL);` when something doesn't work?

Comment: @popnoodles I checked it again. The second line is wrong for some reason.

Comment: Can you show all the code from connecting to the db (remove the connection details) to iterating the results set

Comment: And can people please stop obsessing about telling anyone who posts code with mysql_ in it that they must immediately use mysqli. There is no rush. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206599/switch-to-mysqli-or-stay-with-mysql

Comment: Well at this point, the only difference I see is that final space at the end of the first query.

Comment: now it's obvious. see my answer

Comment: Just for kicks, since this is way mysterious.  Try this: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM REG_USERS where USERNAME='$username' and PASSWORD='$password'") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: And this: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM REG_USERS where USERNAME='{$_POST['username']}' and PASSWORD='{$_POST['password']}'") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: This is why **too localized** questions shouldn't be answered in the first place. OP just didn't comprehend variable scope, refused to show the actual code, or read the obvious error messages. Personal debugging session, of no use to future users.

Comment: I hate myself these times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK now we have the WHOLE code it's obvious.

`$username` and `$password` aren't global. The function doesn't know what they are set to.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

echo 'username: ' . $username . '<br>';  //myname
echo 'password: ' . $password . '<br>';  //mypass

function checkpass()
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    //$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM REG_USERS where USERNAME='$_POST[username]' and PASSWORD='$_POST[password]' ") or die(mysql_error());  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM REG_USERS where USERNAME='" . $username . "' and PASSWORD='" . $password . "'") or die(mysql_error());  
    return  mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

**NB I know about mysqli. OP isn't asking about it, I'm not obsessing about it** but I have added mysql_real_escape_string for good measure.

Comment: What a noob mistake. Thank you.

Comment: You're not obsessing about it? Does that mean you're not discouraging the use of it?

Comment: Given the code in the first place, all of us would have spotted it.

Comment: Can I just point out mario commented about using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` - PHP would have told you those variables weren't set.

Answer (score 0):

Let's set aside the issues with mysql interface (not good to use going forward) and the fact that **you really really don't want to** put any kind of user affected variables straight into your sql strings [SQL injection!!!!], you say the following in your description that this:

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM REG_USERS where

USERNAME='" . $username . "' and PASSWORD='" . $password . "'") or die(mysql_error());`

doesn't work.

Why would it? `$username` and `$password` are set to nothing.  In your first example, you first set them to something, but then you don't use them (you use the straight `$_POST` variables instead).

In your second example, you don't set them.

So does the following work (note you don't need to concatenate the  variables to get them into the string here)?

```
   $username = $_POST['username'];  
   $password = $_POST['password'];  

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM REG_USERS where  
   USERNAME='$username' and PASSWORD='$password'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Again, make sure you never actually do this in real code (just putting variables right into the SQL string).  Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: I don't think the examples are isolated such that those vars aren't set, but I have asked for the whole code, just to check. No response yet.

Comment: I had missed that in the comments.

Comment: THe examples are not isolated, of course, so this answer is pointless.

Comment: Ok, but if you improve this in the question that will be evident.

Comment: And did you double check whether my snippet also failed?  That would be interesting to know although it would not answer you question yet.

Comment: And are you running both of your examples with the same user/pass?

Comment: I have just copy pasted a block from your code and updated the question with it. I am using the same user-pass pair always.

Comment: Ok, good to know.  (I figured you would).

Comment: Thank you all guys for trying to help me. Even though popnoodles found the error, I am going with PDO. Looks like I have a lot to read in the upcoming days.

Comment: Final comment. @popnoodles totally fixed this.  But you see the value of truly clarifying what code is being executed, which is what I was trying to achieve in my stuff (and so was popnoodles all along).  So this kind of answer may not seem helpful, and may not be the answer that should ultimately get the vote (@popnoodles answer rightly earned it), but it can still really help clarity.  And it's hard to do in comments.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution using `mysqli_`:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT USERNAME FROM REG_USERS WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST[username], $_POST[password]);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $USERNAME);

    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    echo "The username is $USERNAME";

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Why downvote this.  @njk provide a helpful example of doing this properly.

Comment: I would imagine because it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @DWright It takes more than a single click to leave a comment. That's why Amazon is so addicting. Nice to see another individual from the Chicago area.

Comment: @popnoodles.  I see.  But if the user follows erdomester follows njk's example, whatever the problem is will clear up and erodmester will have some nice, correct code.  i.e., njk erodmester will find the question to have been answered in any case.

Comment: I wouldn't say that with confidence because it doesn't look like there's actually anything wrong with the code given. Changing 1 line the OP understands into many using something new to them probably won't help.

Comment: Per [SO's FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer), *"Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative."* Seems like this is quite a viable alternative.

Comment: Let's be fair. Now we've been given the whole code you can see this wouldn't have fixed the issue.

Comment: @popnoodles Actually, it would have. My code uses `$_POST`.

Comment: so you have. my bad. but they would never have understood what was wrong and it didn't answer the question which was why wasn't it working.