# My database connection class will not connect to the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Basically I am trying to create a class to handle Database connections. I have double checked to make sure that my connection variables are correct and they work if I plug them directly into the PHP page. But when I call the class like this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . 'includes/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
```

It doesn't work. Here is my code. Maybe I am missing something.

```
<?php

// Class file to connect to database
class DB_CONNECT {

    // constructor
    function __construct()
    {
        // connection to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct()
    {
        // disconnecting from database
        $this->close();
    }

    // Function for Database Connection
    function connect()
    {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once _DIR_ . '/db_config.php';

        // connection to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die (mysql_error());

        // selecting database
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die (mysql_error()) or die (mysql_error());

        // returning connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    // Function to close db connection
    function close()
    {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Its just a comment, but why reinvent the wheel when you could be using an ORM ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Please explain what you expect to happen, what is really happening, and what you have tried to fix it. Include any error messages or log information that may be relevant.

Comment: Your example call includes `require_once __DIR__...`; your class includes `require_once _DIR_...`

Comment: This isn't right: `or die (mysql_error()) or die (mysql_error())`

Comment: is this `db_config.php`? if not: show it

Comment: Can you verify that `__DIR__` is defined?  It is new to php 5.3.0.  Furthermore as @andrewsi said the `__DIR__` in your function is missing a set of underscores.

Comment: @BjoernRennhak, he's not even reinventing an ORM - he's only reinventing PDO...  except without exceptions and using the deprecated mysql extension.

Comment: If you're still writing your first few database lines, stop what you're doing with `mysql_` functions and move to `mysqli_` - `mysql_` is deprecated.

Comment: @jterry so should I go ahead and replace all the mysql_ instances with mysqli_ ?

Comment: It's not quite that simple, but you're not far off. There are lots of resources out there, like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640520/changing-this-from-mysql-to-mysqli), to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your `connect()` function:

```
require_once _DIR_ . '/db_config.php';
```

Should be:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
```

You need the double underscores, otherwise PHP will be looking in the root directory of the server for the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    function connect(){
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect("localhost",$this->user,$this->password);
        if (!$this->conn){
            echo "No DB connection"; 
            exit;
        }
        $this->db = mysqli_select_db("DB_NAME");
        if (!$this->db){
            echo "Can't find DB";
            exit;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `_DIR_` with `dirname(__FILE__)`

Also mysql is deprecated as the @jterry said.